# TypeScript and Angular 1 DI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using Angular 1 with TypeScript and ES6 modules (loaded via SystemJS) and was wondering what would be a good practice to import dependency-injected services.

here's the component:

```
// foo.component.ts
import { DummyService } from  './dummy.service';

class FooCtrl {
    constructor (
       dummyService: DummyService // ERROR: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dummyServiceProvider <- dummyService
    ) {
       dummyService.go();
    }
}

angular.module('app')
  .component('foo', {
    template: 'Hello World',
    controller: FooCtrl
});

// console.log(DummyService); // uncommenting this line 'fixes' the problem
```

and the service:

```
// dummy.service.ts    
export class DummyService () {
    go () {
      console.log('go');
    }
}
angular.service('dummyService', DummyService);
```

the snippet above throws an error as per the comments. the issue is that the file dummy.service.ts does not get imported in the transpiled code - TypeScript ignores it during transpilation because it is only used in the type annotation in FooCtrl constructor. as soon as the imported variable is used in the actual code, the error is gone. possible solutions below.

enforce importing the service file:

```
import { DummyService } from  './dummy.service';
import './dummy.service'; // this works but it's not elegant and breaks DRY
```

imitate ng2 so that TS compiler sees the DummyService class being used:

```
angular.module('app')
  .component('foo', {
    template: 'Hello World',
    controller: FooCtrl,
    providers: [DummyService] // fixes the issue, the providers property has no effect on the ng application
});
```

any thoughts?

Comment: underlying issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4717

Comment: I found the same problem and for now my hacky solution is to do DummyService;, that empty statement forces typescript to load and its a little bit better thant doing another import... still hacky, let me know if you find another workaround

Comment: I know it's too late but I am going through the same thing right now. Did you ever find a solution to this ?

Comment: This should be possible in TS 3.8 as they introduced [Type-Only Imports and Export](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8/#type-only-imports-exports)